# How to get all the values associated with an object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var array = [
    { name:"test0", value:"0" },
    { name:"test1", value:"1" },
    { name:"test2", value:"2" },
    { name:"test0", value:"3" },
    { name:"test0", value:"4" }
];
```

How do I get the value(s) of all the element names associated with `test0` using a loop in javascript?

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
{0,3,4}
```

Comment: sample output is not a valid data format in javascript

Comment: are you saying `[0,3,4]`? + your JSON is not valid (Missing comma's)

Comment: Maybe you are expecting ["0","3","4"]. And your array is missing commas (,)

Comment: in order to help you properly, i'd like to know what is your current javascript knowledge? do you know how to access a property of an object, for example?

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop with an if condition? Please add the code you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter the values and map the desired ones.

`array.filter` allows you to filter items of an array with a condition, so using `i => i.name === 'test0'` will return a new array where only the values with name 'test0' are acquired. Finally, using `map` you create a new array, whose values are the result of the callback function provided. So, using `map(i => i.value)` will return the property `.value` of each (filtered) object.

If you're expecting the values to be numeric, remember to cast them to integers.

```js
var array = [
    { name:"test0", value:"0" },
    { name:"test1", value:"1" },
    { name:"test2", value:"2" },
    { name:"test0", value:"3" },
    { name:"test0", value:"4" }
];

var res = array.filter(i => i.name === 'test0').map(i => i.value);
console.log(res);
```

Otherwise, you can do that in a single shot with reduce:

```js
var array = [
    { name:"test0", value:"0" },
    { name:"test1", value:"1" },
    { name:"test2", value:"2" },
    { name:"test0", value:"3" },
    { name:"test0", value:"4" }
];

var res = array.reduce((a,b) => {
  return b.name === 'test0' && a.push(+b.value), a;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

In this last example, the values are casted to integers using the unary operator (`+`).

Finally, as requested, here is another approach not relying on any array prototype:

```js
var array = [
    { name:"test0", value:"0" },
    { name:"test1", value:"1" },
    { name:"test2", value:"2" },
    { name:"test0", value:"3" },
    { name:"test0", value:"4" }
];

// init a new empty array.
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var item = array[i]; // not mandatory but easy enough to read: acquire the current looped value.
  if (item.name === 'test0') { // if the looped item name is 'test0', join the if.
    res.push(Number(item.value)); // if so, push the item's value, and cast it to a number (using Number).
  }
}
console.log(res); // log the result.
```

Comment: op cleary doesn't know js at all, so saying "just" filter and map is waaay too much

Comment: could you please do it with a loop and if condition?

Comment: @JackChen sure, I will ad an example with that case too.

Comment: @JackChen I've added another example with a regular for loop, explaining each line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can using array filter. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const result = array.filter(a=> a.name === "test0");

console.log(result.map(w => w.value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
    { name:"test0", value:"0" },
    { name:"test1", value:"1" },
    { name:"test2", value:"2" },
    { name:"test0", value:"3" },
    { name:"test0", value:"4" }
];

var test0 = array.filter(item => item.name == "test0").map(item => item.value);

console.log(test0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the objects and get a numerival value with mapping.

```js
var array = [{ name: "test0", value: "0" }, { name: "test1", value: "1" }, { name: "test2", value: "2" }, { name: "test0", value: "3" }, { name: "test0", value: "4" }],
    result = array
        .filter(({ name }) => name === 'test0')
        .map(({ value }) => +value);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var array = [
  { name:"test0", value:"0" },
  { name:"test1", value:"1" },
  { name:"test2", value:"2" },
  { name:"test0", value:"3" },
  { name:"test0", value:"4" }
 ];
 var Rs=[];
 for(var i in array){
  if(array[i]["name"]=="test0")
   Rs.push(i);//Rs.push(array[i]["value"]);
 }
 console.log(Rs);
```

Simple loop is beast!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
    { name:"test0", value:"0" },
    { name:"test1", value:"1" },
    { name:"test2", value:"2" },
    { name:"test0", value:"3" },
    { name:"test0", value:"4" }
];
let output = array.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => {
 if(name === 'test0') {
  return [...acc, value];
 }
 return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create a generic function in which you just need to pass the key value and array and it will filter out the arry on the basic of parameters  

  var array = [
        { name:"test0", value:"0" },
        { name:"test1", value:"1" },
        { name:"test2", value:"2" },
        { name:"test0", value:"3" },
        { name:"test0", value:"4" }
    ];

    function filterList(keyValue, list) {
        let filteredList = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i]["name"] === keyValue) {
                filteredList.push(list[i]["value"]);
            }
        }
        return filteredList;
    }

    console.log(filterList("test0", array));
```